# populate validation for textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Goodmorning Guys,
I have problems with validating a value in a textbox. i have a dropdownlist with   3 phases in it. On selecting one of them, the textbox below is populating the following percents: 20, 40, and 60. It must also be possible to insert the percents manualy so i put a session in it. but this value cant be lower than the percent what is selected from the dropdownlist. For now my code is like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string txt = txtpercents.Text;
       Session["percents"] = txt;
    int ddlchoise = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPhase.SelectedIndex);

        if (ddlchoise == 1)
        {
            txtpercents.Text = "20";

        }

        if (ddlchoise == 2)
        {
            txtpercents.Text = "40";
        }

        if (ddlchoise == 3)
        {
            txtpercents.Text = "60";
        }

         }

private void InsertObj()
{
  int percents = Convert.ToInt32(txtpercents.Text);
        int attemp = Convert.ToInt32(Session["percent"]);
        if (attemp > percents )
        {

             txtpercents.Text = (string)Session["percent"];
 Theobject.Percent = int.Parse(txtpercents.Text);
               }

   }
```

this works but i have to populate a error message or validation when the manualy entered value is lower than the selected phase in the dropdownlist. 
Anyone who can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used that in the else statement like customvalidator1.Isvalid = false; But it didnt work. How would you use it? i'm not so familiar with asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

aspx:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtpercents"
                    ErrorMessage="Only 20,40 or 60 are allowed for percents" 
                    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string[] allowed = { "20", "40", "60" };
    args.IsValid = allowed.Contains(txtpercents.Text.Trim());
}
```

You can also porovide a [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with javascript, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further informations.

If you want a dynamic approach which works even if someone adds other percentages to the `DropDownList` and forgets to add them to the `ServerValidate`:

```
int percent;
var allowed = ddlchoise.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Select(li => li.Text)
    .Where(t => int.TryParse(t, out percent));
```

**Update** acc. comment:

> What im trying to do is: if the user selects phase 2 than te textbox
>   populates 40 as value. It shouldnt be possible to edit the value to
>   less than 40 because the selected item in the dropdownlist is pahse 2.

You could still use the code above, you just need to change it a little bit:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    int percent;
    int selectedPercentage = int.Parse(ddlchoise.SelectedItem.Text);
    var allowed = ddlchoise.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
       .Select(li => li.Text)
       .Where(t => int.TryParse(t, out percent) && percent >= selectedPercentage);
    args.IsValid = allowed.Contains(txtpercents.Text.Trim());
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. What im trying to do is: if the user selects phase 2 than te textbox populates 40 as value. It shouldnt be possible to edit the value to less than 40 because the selected item in the dropdownlist is pahse 2.  The array looks for the values but i need a function where it can see if it is not less than te selected value. Any idea? thanks again